# Is there a better way to persist a map with the value being a set?

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary

I'm looked a lot into being able to use Hibernate to persist a map like `Map<String, Set<Entity>>` with little luck (especially since I want it all to be on one table).

[Mapping MultiMaps with Hibernate](http://blog.xebia.com/2007/10/05/mapping-multimaps-with-hibernate/) is the thing that seems to get referenced the most, which describes in detail how to go about implementing this using a `UserCollectionType`.

I was wondering, since that was written over four years ago, is there any better way of doing it now?

So, for example, I would like to have on `EntityA` a map like `Map<String, Set/List<EntityB>>`.

There would be two tables: `EntityA` and `EntityB` (with `EntityB` having a foreign key back to `EntityA`).

I don't want any intermediate tables.

Comment: I don't see why this is worthy of downvoting or closing. There was a "best" way presented but was four years old. I don't think it's unreasonable to ask if there's a better way now. Perhaps I should have qualified better as less verbose or simpler, but still it's not really argumentative or an opinion. There's either an answer or there's not.

Comment: +1 to compensate the downvote. IMO a legal question.

Comment: By the way when you say in "one table" do you mean the same table as the class of which the map is a field?

Comment: @UstamanSangat I do not. So, it would be EntityA has a Map<String, Set<EntityB>>.

Comment: @AHungerArtist, and you want a DB table EntityA and a table EnityB, whose key is the composite of [the map-key and the foreign key to EntityA], right?

Comment: @UstamanSangat Edited my answer to include a clearer example. Whether it's a composite key to those things or has its own unique key doesn't really matter -- either one I could work with.

Answer (score 1):

The way how its done on my current project is that we transforming beans/collections to xml using xstream:

```
public static String toXML(Object instance) {
    XStream xs = new XStream();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    xs.marshal(instance, new CompactWriter(writer));
    return writer.toString();
}
```

and then using Lob type in hibernate for persisting :

```
@Lob
@Column(nullable = false)
private String data;
```

I found this approach very generic and you could effectively implement flexible key/value storage with it. You you don't like XML format then Xstream framework has inbuilt driver for transforming objects to JSON. Give it a try, its really cool.

Cheers

EDIT: Response to comment.
Yes, if you want to overcome limitations of classic approach you are probably sacrifice something like indexing and/or search. You stil could implement indexing/searching/foreign/child relationships thru collections/generic entity beans by yourself - just maintain separate key/value table with property name/property value(s) for which you think search is needed.

I've seen number of database designs for products where flexible and dynamic(i.e. creation new attributes for domain objects without downtime) schema is needed and many of them use key/value tables for storing domain attributes and references from owner objects to child one. Those products cost millions of dollars (banking/telco) so I guess this design is already proven to be effective.

Sorry, that's not answer to your original question since you asked about solution without intermediate tables.

Comment: Interesting solution. However, this makes it pretty difficult/inefficient to use in a search, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

It depends :) When things are getting complex, you should understand what your application is doing.

In some situation, you may represent your Set as a TreeSet, and represent this TreeSet in an ordered coded String, such as ["1", "8", "12"] where 1, 8, 12 are primary keys, and then *let's write code* !

Obviously, it's not a general answer for, in my opinion, a too general question.